# Whats the most interesting to build with 7400 series

Tags: ttl

I'm currently doing a project and have no idea what to build

Comment: Skill level, budget (time and money)? Two students of me be building a CPU, probably 32-bit.

Answer (score 1):

7400 - Hopefully CMOS version of?
 74HCxx, ... ?

Assuming relatively low complexity to start:

Clock - see things happen that people understand

Dice - similar

Quizz machine - lock in 1st button press - simple and some use

Binary Clock - Nerd value. Useful. Gets comment and notice.

...